# Run same R script from terminal with different arguments in parallel

Tags: r, tmux

I have an R script that's called the following way from the terminal:

```
Rscript myscript.R param1 param2
```

When the script finishes it generates an output .csv file that is saved somewhere on my server.

I want to be able to, by using *tmux*, on different panes, run the same script, just with different values for `param1` `param2`.

How do I go about to do that? Really struggling to find the best way to do it.

Comment: you can rename output file to `paste0("output_", param1, "_", param2, ".csv")`

Comment: my problem is not with overwriting the output file. The problem is I can't run the 2 at the same time.
I get "Error: unexpected symbol in "Script started"" when I try to.

Comment: You might want to add the tag [tmux] to your question, or maybe asked it here 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmux

Comment: It is possible that the script is not correct. Usually an `unexpected symbol` refers to a syntax error in a r script. Another possibility is that executing 2 r scripts at the same time might use the same core (one R process). In that case, you can take a look at the `parallel` R package.

Comment: You need to either solve the error and then run with 2 parallel scripts, or introduce tmux. Not that tmux is a terminal splitter, and you would open R sessions to send in R commands, not really call for complete R-files.

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution I managed to get to this problem was to basically start R sessions on each tmux window and from there just input the arguments and run the actual script.

Not the most practical but gets the job done.